# Mocha async hooks not running?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, mocha.js, puppeteer

I am always getting page as being undefined in this structure. It seems none of mocha's hooks are running. I tried adding `async` to the top level describe, I tried adding done statements. I even tried using `Promise.then.catch`. All with no luck.

```
const should = require('chai').should()
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

const puppeteerConfig = {
    headless: true,
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-translate', '--disable-extensions', '--disable-sync']
}

var browser
var page

describe('...', function() {

    before(async function() {
        browser = await puppeteer.launch(puppeteerConfig)
    })

    after(async function() {
        await browser.close()
    })

    beforeEach(async function() {
        page = await browser.newPage()
    })

    afterEach(async function() {
        await page.close()
    })

    describe('...', async function() {
        before(async function() {
            console.log(page) // undefined
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: You are writing console inside `describe`, try writing inside an `it`.

Comment: I forgot the `before` in the second describe, it does some work, then runs a few `it` statements.

Comment: Sadly the execution order is such https://gist.github.com/harto/c97d2fc9d0bfaf20706eb2acbf48c908

Comment: I think you could use selenium-js, which has some good async Mocha examples / API.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Akshendra Pratap, that gist showed why that before failed. What I did was create a top level function:

```
async function genHTML(page) {
    return await page.$(...)
}
```

Then called that inside the first describe's `beforeEach()`. This solved it, very odd design that mocha would call the upper then lower before's, before calling the upper beforeEach...